# PHP constant set inside class, but I need to alter it outside the class now, can this be done?

Tags: php, class, variables, constants

I have a simple core class that is being used for core functions to a small web app. I have defined some constants in the class - which has mostly static functions - and I am wanting to set / edit these constants outside of the class, example:

```
class core{
  const connection = '';
  public static function someSqlScript(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE someconditions";
    $exec = mysqli_query(self::connection, $sql);  
  }
}
```

Now, I want to be able to set the connection constant so that it references a mysql connection object, which (by means of another script), has already been assigned to the variable $con, so essentially I am after something like this:

```
core::connection = $con; //send connection for use in class
core::someSqlScript(); //should not perform the MySQL query using conneciton $con as above
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am used to using non static functions and variables within classes, but the static functions with constants has got me.

Thanks to all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP constants declaration based on condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659302/php-constants-declaration-based-on-condition)

Comment: Apologies if it is, I did search for a related question but did not come across one that I thought was a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of **constant** is, that you can't change it. You want a static **variable**:

```
class core{
  public static $connection = '';
  public static function someSqlScript(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE someconditions";
    $exec = mysqli_query(self::$connection, $sql);  
  }
}

core::$connection = $con; 
core::someSqlScript();
```

Note the `public static $connection` instead of `const connection` and `self::$connection` instead of `self::connection` (also `core::$connection` instead of `core::connection`).

Comment: thank you for a very informative response, much appreciated, you cleared all my misunderstandings up in one paragraph! * kisses your feet *

Comment: I did, had to wait 'x' amount of minutes before system allowed me to accept as answer ;)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry then. Just saw the comment and no green check mark, and was a bit disappointed ;)

Answer (score 2):

The idea of [constants](http://nl.php.net/constants) is, that they cannot be changed after their definition.