# Are getters the only way I can prevent changes to public properties?

Tags: php, getter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Readonly Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402215/php-readonly-properties)

I want a  property to be publicly visible:

`echo $object->prop;`

but I don't want to be modifiable.

Are there other options to make this happen, besides using `__get`?

Comment: Are you looking for read only properties? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402215/php-readonly-properties

Comment: yes, something like that. But the solution you linked uses __get too

Comment: If you don't want to use `__get`, then yes, getter methods are the best bet. You could alternatively implement `ArrayAccess` but this likely isn't any more performant that `__get`

Comment: As an alternative to to __get() and regular getter/setter I sometimes take approach to copy public properties to protected/private when object needs to enter a "locked" state. Not quite the same as making them read-only, but reduces mess while maintaining performance when nothing really cares about the values from outside. :)

Comment: the question is somewhat misphrased. if you want to modify a property you use a setter. A getter only provides access to the property. The magic methods __get and __set are not Getters and Setters though. They are error handlers that get triggered when trying to access/mutate an inaccessible property.

Comment: there is no other way to do read only public properties. many might suggest that you make the property protected and just make a getter method. $object->getProp().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there other options to make this happen, besides using __get?

No, but there is feature request for it: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46506 so you can vote for importance of it and hope that this will be resolved in near future.

But I don't think it will be near future since this feature will create a lot of confusion, like objects stored in properties - they are only references to the object, so making them visible allows you to operate on it's methods / properties.

As for now, creating proper getter for every property, that you want to be read-only, seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Other ways I can think of:

1. Use a `__set()` function and ignore the setting.
2. Don't use that variable at all, but create a getVal() function, and no setVal() function.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: #1 won't work if the variable is visible to outsiders -- `__set` only runs when someone tries to set a property that doesn't exist, or is private.  In cases where `__set` would run, you'd need a `__get` too.